# Error A2105 : Expected : instruction or directive - MASM

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm making a simple program to check the largest 32 bit number in a given set using MASM. Currently I'm running DOSBOX on Mac BigSur. I have a folder 8086 in which I have MASM.exe , TASM.exe, TD.exe, BIN2HEX.exe, DEBUG.exe, EDIT.COM, EXE2BIN.exe LINK.exe.
My code is

```
.model tiny
.386
.data
dat1 dd 45687902h,89177688h,9008123dh,842943abh,93649571h
max1 dd ?
.code
.startup
    lea si,dat1
    mov cx,5
    lodsd
X1: cmp eax,[si]
     jae x2
     mov eax,[si]
X2: add si,4
     loop x1
     mov max1,eax
.exit
end
```

The error I am getting is - 
`asm(7): error A2105: Expected: instruction or directive`
`asm(17): error A2105: Expected: instruction or directive`
corresponding to the .startup and .exit lines.
I have no idea why is this happening.

Comment: Dosbox hints you are using 16 bit. Microsoft documentation says those directives are only supported under 32 bit.

Comment: @Jester how do I change it to 32 bit? Sorry I'm just beginning to use this.

Comment: Well, which do you want - a 16-bit program (to run in DOS or DOSBOX), or a 32-bit program (to run in Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

You are making several mistakes in your code:

1. You are mixing 16-bit and 32-bit code. The directive `.model tiny` has usually been used for 16-bit DOS `.COM` files which had all code+data in one 64kb segment. This approach is ancient and not used nowadays.
2. Because you used the `.386` directive, it can be assumed that you want to use 32-bit code. (A valid argument against that assumption is the choice of your toolset. This answer is only partially applicable for 16-bit code). For this, the above `.model` directive should rather be

   ```
    .model flat, stdcall
   ```

   This specifies a FLAT memory model with an STDCALL calling convention, see [here at MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-model?view=msvc-160) for more info on that. The `FLAT` denotes a linear and flat address space, and `STDCALL` denotes a specific [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) (which is not relevant for you, because you do not do any calls).
3. So, because you use 32-bit code, your pointers have to be 32-bit, too. Therefore change `SI` to `ESI`. Also change `CX` to `ECX`, because the (legacy) [`LOOP` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/loop:loopcc) also assumes a 32-bit value due to the 32-bit address size.

Fixing some other minor logical errors of your code, a working approach could be the following:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.data
  dat1 dd 45687902h,89177688h,9008123dh,842943abh,93649571h
.data?
  max1 dd ?
.code
start:
    lea esi, dat1
    mov ecx, 5     ; number of elements in the array
    mov edx, 0     ; EDX = MAX VALUE starts with the lowest possible value 0
X1: lodsd          ; load current value
    cmp edx, eax
    jae X2         ; value is not greater or equal
    mov edx, eax   ; set new greatest value
X2: loop X1        ; decrement ECX and loop if greater than 0
    mov max1, edx  ; set variable 'max1' to largest value in EDX
end start
```

Of course, this code does not include any output or exit code.
But it will work in a debugger.

Comment: We don't know what is the intended target. Note that it is entirely legal to use 32 bit operand size in 16 bit real mode if you have a 386 processor.

Comment: @Jester: Yes. I just realized that and put a disclaimer into the answer.

Comment: The dat1 address is known during compilation. I'd suggest replacing "lea esi, dat1" with "mov esi, offset dat1". LEA is best used during runtime, plus it generates more bytes 8d3500204000 versus using mov/offset combo be00204000 Also, explaining the instruction "lodsd" moves the value located at dat1 pointed to by esi into the eax register, followed by adding 4 to esi.